# How to indicate inherited class and use wildcards in scala partial function?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
seq.collect {case clazz: SomeClass => clazz}
```

can return a collection of instances of SomeClass and seems working well.

But if I do:

```
seq.collect {case _ <: SomeClass => _}
seq.collect {case clazz <: SomeClass => clazz}
```

They both fail. What is the correct syntax to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution already does what you want. Since `case x: SomeClass` also matches subclasses.

Consider:

```
class A
class B extends A

Seq(new A(), new B(), "bar") collect {
  case x: A => x
}
```

This will give you `Seq(A@..., B@...)` as you wish and is typed `Seq[A]`.